# Youtube bottombar

Tags: android, youtube, bottombar

Anyone know how to find out how the new youtube bottombar was made? Was it a custom library (I doubt) or did they come up with a native way for creating a bottombar. Is there a way to get the code? It looks pretty good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called **BottomNavigationView**, take a look to the followink links:

Android developers: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

Tutorial: https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0